# gsubfn in R, how to conditionally replace only second set of numbers in a set of strings

Tags: r, regex, replace

I'm struggling to find the syntax to replace only the second set of integers in a string

I have this

```
initpop <- c("a-00-04","a-00-00","a-00-00", "dead", "a-00-00")
 initpop
[1] "a-00-04" "a-00-00" "a-00-00" "dead"    "a-00-00"
```

For each of the strings in this array I would like to increment the last set of integers by one, if the value < 4, and reset to 0 if value == 4.  I'm attempting to do it in pieces but struggle with the simplest of regex to specify the second set of numbers, not both

> gsubfn("[[:digit:]]+", function(x) as.numeric(x)+1, initpop[1])
>   [1] "a-1-1"

What I'd like to get back is

```
[1] "a-00-00" "a-00-01" "a-00-01" "dead" "a-00-01"
```

I realise it is simple, just beyond me. Any suggestions.  Thx. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
gsubfn(
  "^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K(\\d+)",
  ~ ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 4, sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(x)+1), "00"),
  initpop,
  perl=TRUE
)
```

Output:

```
[1] "a-00-00" "a-00-01" "a-00-01" "dead"    "a-00-01"
```

The regex - `^\D*\d+\D*\K(\d+)` is parsed with the PCRE engine (due to `perl=TRUE`) and matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (first set of digits)
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits (the second set).

The `~ ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 4, sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(x)+1), "00")` part is the replacement: if `x` is less than 4, the incremented value is returned padded with initial 0s, else, `00` is returned. This can be adjusted.

Comment: If we can assume the second set of digits comes at the end then could also consider this variation:  `gsubfn("\\d+$", ~ sprintf("%02d", (as.numeric(x) + 1) %% 5), initpop)`